# Pandas Groupby multiple columns with cumcount

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python
I have a dataset where the same customer can apply for a product multiple times in a day and have fields for cust_number and date

when I apply

```
df['g']=dfc.groupby('CustNo','DATE').cumcount()
```

python errors

```
ValueError: No axis named DATE for object type DataFrame
```

is there an easy solution? I think an assignment of axis'?

help please

Comment: apologies I then want to merge two dataframes by custno, date and g (as i said the custno, date combo can produce duplicates which throws python into a paddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns/groupers to use in [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) should be passed as the **first** parameter. Here you pass two parameters, so the second is considered to be the `axis`:

```
DataFrame.groupby(by=None, axis=0, level=None, as_index=True, sort=True,
                  group_keys=_NoDefault.no_default, squeeze=_NoDefault.no_default,
                  observed=False, dropna=True)
```

You need to wrap the column names in a list:

```
dfc.groupby(['CustNo', 'DATE']).cumcount()
```

Comment: Thank You, much appreciated (I may one day get a handle on the slivery beast of python but until then this really helped)

Answer (score 0):

check the column name in your data frame, whether "DATE" column is exist. if the date column is exist in ur data frame, first you need to change the date format, follow the below step.

import datetime

#use below syntax to convert your date column into date format
df['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question

Comment: thank you, i checked this